# why won't my drop-box be populated correctly using a while statement?

Tags: php

i have a problem with a drop-box that isn't populated correctly.

```
echo"<td>Selectati numarul de telefon:</td>
<td><select name='mobil'>
<option value='--'>---</option>";

while($apelantRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($apelantResult))
{
    $apel=(string)$apelantRow['nrtel'];
    echo "<option value='".$apel."'>$apel</option>";
}

echo"</select></td></tr>";
```

the sql query works fine. what i get is something like this:

```
<option value='2'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
```

I really don't know what to do. what is confusing me is that i have the same code, on an other page, with different variables and it works just fine.

please help.

thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: What output are you expecting? Could it be there is another column in $apelantRow that you need to be putting in instead of showing the number twice?

Comment: Is this code complete? Looks weird to me that a variable `$aple` does have two values at the same time. I *cannot* reproduce the problem based on your code (without SQL): http://codepad.org/uX1W0Stb

Comment: @user495812 i want to populate the drop-box, with the same text as value.

Comment: Are you sure you get this HTML as result? Could it be a problem of your form processing script? As I said, I can't reproduce the error, so this part of the code should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not

```
echo '<option value="'.$apel.'">'.$apel.'</option>';
```

?

EDIT : explicit cast doesn't required as variable is used in a string

Comment: Maybe a conflict with register_globals?